# Vite using wrong host ip

Tags: laravel, docker, vite

So I'm using docker to start vite dev server, I start server with `vite --host` and it works perfectly fine when I try to access it via `http://localhost:513`

[image: vite working]

However, if I open my webapp, seems like vite is injecting wrong url and this error appears in my console:

```
[::]:5173/resources/js/index.tsx:1          Failed to load resource: net::ERR_ADDRESS_INVALID
```

page source looks like this:

When i look into page source, it looks like that wrong href is injected

```html
<script type="module" src="http://[::]:5173/@vite/client"></script><link rel="stylesheet" href="http://[::]:5173/resources/sass/app.scss" /><script type="module" src="http://[::]:5173/resources/js/index.tsx"></script>
```

Vite console output:

```
VITE v4.1.1  ready in 16398 ms
  ➜  Local:   http://localhost:5173/
  ➜  Network: http://172.24.0.4:5173/
  LARAVEL v9.52.3  plugin v0.7.4
  ➜  APP_URL: http://teddy.test
```

What might I have been doing wrong ?

Comment:  Please post code, errors, sample data or textual output here as plain-text, not as images that can be hard to read, can’t be copy-pasted to help test code or use in answers, and are barrier to those who depend on screen readers or translation tools. You can edit your question to add the code in the body of your question. For easy formatting use the `{}` button to mark blocks of code, or indent with four spaces for the same effect. The contents of a **screenshot can’t be searched, run as code, or easily copied and edited to create a solution.**

Comment: `::` is localhost in ipv6. it looks like a bad replacement somewhere

Comment: @apokryfos where that may happen ? I updated my question with vite output too

Answer (score 1):

Fixed by adding `server.hmr` configuration in `vite.config.ts`

```
export default defineConfig({

    plugins: [
        laravel({
            input: [
                'resources/js/index.tsx',
                'resources/sass/app.scss'
            ],
            refresh: true,
        }),
        react({
            fastRefresh: false
        })
    ],
    server: {
        hmr: {
            host: 'localhost' /* HERE */
        }
    }

});
```